# Como renderizar imagens dinâmicas com angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Possuo um objeto no seguinte formato:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro do objeto principal tem um objeto chamado upload.
Esse objeto contem informações das imagens a serem renderizadas.

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
ng-src="{{o.way}}{{o.original_filename}}"
```

Mas não funciona de forma alguma. Retorna a mensagem :

**Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating: {{o.way}}/{{o.original_filename}}
Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.**

Achei algo sobre o $sce ms n me ajudou mt.

Estou usando uma biblioteca do angular pra fazer um slide.

```
<slidecontainer ng-repeat="o in dataProject.upload.data">
    <slide ng-src="{{o.way}}/{{o.original_filename}}"></slide>
</slidecontainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de tentar concatenar os dois valores no html, crie um método no controller que concatene os valores:

```
$scope.getProjectUploadUrl = function (project) {
  return project.way + project.original_filename;
};
```

...então no html você chama esse método dessa forma:

```
<slidecontainer ng-repeat="o in dataProject.upload.data">
    <slide ng-src="{{getProjectUploadUrl(o)}}"></slide>
</slidecontainer>
```

---

Aparentemente essa diretiva não te permite especificar mais de uma expressão, conforme pode ser visto [nesse link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#you-can-only-bind-one-expression-to-src-ng-src-or-action-).

Comment: consegui assim : 
<img data-ng-src="{{image.way + image.original_filename}}">

Comment: Interessante. Na verdade esse atributo do angular exige que você utilize no máximo uma expressão, sendo que cada `{{ }}` representa uma expressão. Nesse teu caso, mesmo que você esteja concatenando valores, essa concatenação está dentro de uma única expressão `{{ }}`, por isso funciona, é até mais simples do que a solução que eu sugeri. Boa!